# How to manage memory for ios with large csv files?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory

I'm new to ios development, and I'm running into issues relating to memory management and my approaches to dealing with large datasets.

Right now, I am loading the csv files and storing the relevant data as objects in memory at app initialization. Some of the csv files are larger than 1MB, and in total, my app uses about 180MB of memory. This is obviously way too high of a number (unless the info I found is wrong and this is an acceptable number, then please let me know).

I feel as though there is a fundamental flaw in my approach: is there a way I can avoid storing the csv files in the project itself? Or, is there a kind of "lazy" loading I can do so that I can simply look up info in the csv file, as opposed to loading all of the data from it at once?

Any help would do. I think that I need a new perspective in how to manage this more efficiently.

EDIT: Most of the information that I need is some sort of key lookup, and the search tree of these lookups may span multiple csv files.

Comment: People will need a bit more information about the nature of the data and, more importantly, the type of access you need.  For example, is it key-value type information where you only need to lookup information for particular keys over the run of the application or is it something you will likely want the bulk of fairly quickly on startup?

Comment: Sounds like you may have a candidate for CoreData, but as @drc said, it's really light on information here.

Comment: See my edit. Sorry, I'm not allowed to be too specific about the details of the project. But, a data element in one of these csvs has a bunch of attributes, and these attributes may point to another data element in another csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic problem is that CSV isn't a good "incremental" storage format. What I mean by that is that you can't effectively load just the part of the data you're interested in into memory - you have to load the whole thing, and then root around for the bits you want.

A better approach will be to copy the data from the CSVs into another data store. [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) is more-or-less the recommended Apple built-in data store, but it comes with a lot of overhead that you may not need. You can also use [SQLite](http://sqlite.org) directly from your application code, or use a thinner Objective-C layer on top of it like [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

You could do that when you build your app, or build code into the app to do that the first time it runs.

After that, you can use the relevant APIs to request just the data you need to do whatever operation you're working on.